# Chart.js graphic return as undefined

Tags: php, chart.js

I am creating a graphic using chart.js. Labels work all right, and graphic has to show type and quantity. Quantity is returned correctly, but type (names) show as undefined and they are light gray, not the colors I chose.

[image: my graphic]

The array is returning correctly (var_dump($array) returned the right names and values). I don't know what else can be the problem. Here are some parts of my code if anyone can help me.

home.php

```
<div class="db-row row2">
   <div class="grid-1">
    <div class="db-info">
        <div class="db-info-title">Tipos de imóveis disponíveis para venda</div>
        <div class="db-info-body" style="height: 300px">
             <canvas id="rel2"></canvas>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $user = new Users();
    $user->setLoggedUser();//captura as info do usuario logado
    $company = new Companies($user->getCompany());//define a empresa (id) do usuario logado
    $data['company_name'] = $company->getName();//define o nome da empresa do usuario logado
    $data['user_email'] = $user->getEmail();//define o email ddo usuario logado

    $i = new Inventory();

    $data['statuses'] = array(
        '0'=>'Casa',
        '1'=>'Condomínio',
        '2'=>'Apartamento',
        '3'=>'Cobertura',
        '4'=>'Loja'
    );

    //imoveis vendidos nos ultimos 30 dias
    $data['products_sold'] = $i->getSoldProducts(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')), date('Y-m-d'),$user->getCompany()); 
    //valor imoveis vendidos ultimos 30 dias 
    $data['revenue']       = $i->getTotalRevenue(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')), date('Y-m-d'),$user->getCompany()); 
    //grafico status        
    $data['status_list']   = $i->getTypeList($user->getCompany());


     $this->loadTemplate('home', $data);
}
```

Model

```
 public function getTypeList($id_company){
    $array = array('0'=>0, '1'=>0, '2'=>0, '3'=>0, '4'=>0);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as total, type "
            . "FROM inventory "
            . "WHERE del IS NULL AND (is_sold IS NULL OR is_sold = '') "
            . "AND id_company = :id_company "
            . "GROUP BY type "
            . "ORDER BY type ASC";
    $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(':id_company', $id_company);
    $sql->execute();

   if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
        $rows = $sql->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rows as $sale_item){
            $array[$sale_item['type']] = $sale_item['total'];
        }
    }              
    return $array;
}
```

JS

```
var rel2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("rel2"), {
type:'pie',
data:{
    labels:status_name_list,
    datasets: [{
        data:status_list,
        backgroundColor:['#0000FF','#32CD32','#FF0000', '#CCFF33', '#663300']
    }]
  }

});
```

Comment: could you please console.log(status_list)?

Comment: Denis, how do I do that? Sorry, I'm only learning.

Comment: try `console.log(status_list)` just above your `var rel2 = new Chart...` , and then watch your browser developer tools (F12) Console

Comment: Denis thank you for the explanation. It shows this:   Array(8)0: 01: 02: 03: 04: 05: "1"6: "1"7: "1"length: 8pop: ƒ ()push: ƒ ()shift: ƒ ()splice: ƒ ()unshift: ƒ ()_chartjs: {listeners: Array(1)}__proto__: Array(0)